# Call of JS method via ExternalInterface from Flash fails in Chrome

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome, flash-builder, externalinterface

I have the following issue.I have a flash movie embedded in HTML page.There is a button which when pressed, a JavaScript method starts calling a function inside the Flash.Then Flash responds by calling a JavaScript  method in the HTML page. This cycle works fine in IE and FireFox. But it doesn't work in Google Chrome.After some debugs I found that the JavaScript method that is supposed to get called from the Flash is never triggered.I can't get why? Here is my code in the Flash:

```
public static function update(transparent:Boolean = true, bgColor:Number = 0xFFFFFFFF, matrix:Matrix = null):void {
    if (!_enabled) return;
    if (_printSource == null) throw new Error("No source specified");
    if (!ExternalInterface.available) throw new Error("External Interface not available");

    var bitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(_printSource.width, _printSource.height, transparent, bgColor);
    bitmap.draw(_printSource, matrix,null,null,null,true);
    _base64encoder.reset();

    _base64encoder.encodeBytes(_pngEncoder.encode(bitmap));
    ExternalInterface.call("FlashPrintFix.setImg", ExternalInterface.objectID, _base64encoder.toString());
    }
```

As you can see this method calls A function called "setImg" from FlashPrintFix JS file.

Now the method in JS looks like this (although its content is not important because it is never triggered in the Chrome:

```
FlashPrintFix.setImg = function(objId, imgData) {

var obj = document.getElementById("graph");
     var obj =  document["graph"];
if (obj === null) {
    throw new Error("Can't find node with id '" + objId + "'");
}

obj.setAttribute("class", "printableFlashObj");

var container = obj.parentNode;
if (container.nodeName === "OBJECT") {
    container = container.parentNode;

}

var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute("class", "flashScreenshot");
img.src = "data:image/png;base64,"+imgData;
img.setAttribute("id", "imgPrnt");
    container.appendChild(img);
   $('imgPrnt').ready(function() {

          alert("Image is loaded");


        });};
```

And this is the code in HTML. Because it is a CakePHP view it doesn't contain all the regular HTML tags by default .Those are generated in runtime by PHP + layout container wrapper.But the following code is responsible for Flash File  Embed and it resides in the HTML page body during runtime:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 var currentUrl=<?php echo "'".XXXXXXX."'" ?>+'/XXX/XXXxXXXXXXX/';
$(document).ready(initApp());

 function initApp(){
  $("#flashContentWrapper").flash(
  {

        swf:currentUrl+<?php echo "'$app_filename'" ?>,
        id:"graph",
        name:"graph",
        allowScriptAccess:"always",
    height:600,
    width:1000,
    flashvars:{ 
        key:<?php echo "'$someKey'"?>
    }
  }
);
```

UPDATE:
Ok guys, discard my theory that the JavaScript is not called via ExternalInterface from Flash.The actual problem was in the FlashPrintFix.js .For all those who use ths plugin for printing Flash content  in Flash print unsupported browsers like Firefox or Chrome should fix this line in the script:

```
 FlashPrintFix.needPrintFix = function () {
   var needF= /chrome|firefox|opera/i.test(navigator.userAgent);//<----Add "chrome" before "firefox"
   alert(needF);
   return  needF;


 };
```

The problem is that by default var needF looks like this:

```
 var needF= /firefox|opera/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

The duty of this variable to return true for a browser that can't print Flash and false for the browser that can .Because by default chrome is not being checked and therefor this var always returns for it true.If it is false the Flash Class for  FlashPrintFix doesn't process the calls on JS side because it thinks that the browser prints Flash fine and everything is all right. Thanks to all.

Comment: A link to a public HTML page would be useful.

Comment: Can't give a link as the product is in the dev process.But I will add the HTML Code above.

Comment: Are you using the Flash debug player in Chrome? I know Chrome uses it's own Flash plugin which by default is not the debug player. You may be getting an error here: `if (!ExternalInterface.available) throw new Error("External Interface not available");` But, without the debug player, you won't get the error message.

Comment: I run it in debug player + I substituted the "throw new Error" with Alert.show() in order to be able to see the errors as popup.I get nothing.No JS method is triggered from inside Flash in Chrome.

Comment: The topic can be closed now.I pinned down the issue.See the Update above.